# Semantic_point_annotator Parameter Explanation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been having some problems with the [Semantic Point Annotator](http://ros.org/wiki/semantic_point_annotator#), i.e. the thing that removes the ground plane from the PR2's obstacle avoidance system. The main problem is that points in the floor show up as obstacles.

The wiki page does not have much in the way of documentation. Does anyone have insight into how the parameters can be fiddled with to remove this problem?

Edit: Alternatively, you can check out the [bag file](http://cse.wustl.edu/%7Edvl1/stuff/ros/tiltscanfiltered.bag)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38960/semantic_point_annotator-parameter-explanation/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That package uses the old, obsolete `sensor_msgs/PointCloud` message.

There is probably a newer implementation using the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) and the newer `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` message.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-07-16**:
That's true, but to my knowledge, it is still what drives the PR2 NavStack (at least up until Electric).

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-07-16**:
There is an updated version that has PointCloud2. https://kforge.ros.org/pr2navigation/hg/rev/8819c61efbb7